# Stuck with form and sending email to input email

Tags: javascript, node.js, email

Hi i'm new to stack and programming, so i have a node project that when i run the server it calls the mandrill api and sends my email template to a hardcoded email, all i want to know is how do i get the email value from a form input field send it to server .js or wherever and send my template to that email

```html
<div class="input-group emailInput emailInput2">
  <form method="post" action="/send-email/invoiceEmail">
    <input type="email" class="form-control input1 target" id="emailAddress" name="email" placeholder="Email Address">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
   <button id="emailAddress2" class="btn btn-secondary input2 emailbtn2 other" type="button" onclick ="validate()">
        <div class="emailbtn">></div>
      </button>
 </span>
  </form>
</div>
```

```js
app.post("/send-email/invoiceEmail", function (req, res) {
 var x = document.getElementById("emailAddress");
 console.log(req.body.email);

 var email = "mail@mail.com";
 emailService.sendInvoiceEmail(email,function(data){
  res.send("success");
 },
 function(error){
  console.log(error);
 })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use bodyparser middleware to read form values. Include this to your main file.

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

Use req.body.email to read the email from the form.